# Dances with Wolves - Does movie title really tells the whole story about the movie?

Tags: american-english, phrases, sentence

A very famous movie title "Dances with Wolves". I just to make sure does name of the title covers the whole story or just an English Phrase.

Comment: What research have you done into the plot of this movie? Why do you think the title is (or isn't) a summary of the story?

Comment: What type of research actually expected? Did wiki. but May be you missed the point. name of the title covers the whole story or just an English Phrase.  not sure can you shade some light. Let me wait someone will definitely come to answer.

Comment: Nadeem Taj, even a cursory knowledge of the plot (e.g. that acquired by seeing the film or reading an account of the plot) would tell you that the 'whole story' of the film is not simply someone dancing with some wolves (much else happens). Thus your question does not make much sense.

Comment: It is not 'an English phrase', it  is a translation of the name given to the protagonist by the Native Americans he befriends.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  because

Comment: of few good men.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its connection to learning English is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dances with Wolves" does not cover the whole plot.  That would be impossible. No title "covers the whole plot", not even long descriptive titles like "Harry Potter and the Philosophers' Stone" (This title doesn't "cover" Ron, Hermione, Hogwarts or Voldemort, for example)

"Dances With Wolves" is the name of the main character of the movie, it doesn't "cover" any of the events of the movie (although some Native American names may have a specific meaning related to the actions of a person).  It is not a common phrase used in English. My understanding of the is that "Dances" is verbal, and the meaning of the name is "He is a person who dances with wolves".

Comment: I can imagine making a film called 'Lincoln's Youth' about the formative years of Abraham Lincoln, and I would hope that the title would cover the plot pretty well. I think it might be a bit dull and possibly flop at the box-office.

Comment: Some titles can cover the plot and not be dull at all. Some examples: **Beach babes from beyond / Hollywood chainsaw hookers / Snakes on a train / Bloodsucking pharaohs in Pittsburgh / Attack of the killer tomatoes / Killer condom / The ghost in the invisible bikini**

Comment: I don't think you could reconstruct the plot from any of those titles.  If someone told you the name of the movie, could you write out the script, or even a treatment of the plot.  Of course not!  A title is a title - it can't "cover the plot" even in relatively plotless movies like "The Ghost in the Invisible Bikini"  could you guess that it is about a ghost of recently deceased old man and his girlfriend (who died young) trying to scare off a lawyer and ensure that  the rightful heir gets his estate, and can have a groovy pool party??? I thought not.

Comment: It covers one even in the movie in the sense that the character was named for an activity he was seen doing.

Comment: @rajesun. These plots will make physically weak. if you ask how. I can explain various ways. If I have a son like you will difinetly recommend to start with Darkness and Honey. or Scent of a Woman (Different topic and different story).